# Advantages of std::string_view when passing to another function taking std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I have the following helper function, which takes in a string view and returns a lookup in an `unordered_map`:

```
int Scanner::getOpCount(std::string_view op) {
    auto itr = Parser::opTable.find(op);
}

// in another file: 
const static std::unordered_map<std::string, OpEntry> opTable;
```

This will not compile because `find` expects a string parameter, so the only solution I've found (correct me if I'm wrong) is to wrap `op` as `string{op}`. What worries me, however, is that `std::string_view` was meant to facilitate easier string passing, but if I have to construct a string from it regardless in the body of the function, then is there any advantage to defining `getOpCount` with a `string_view` parameter? Or is this equivalent, if not slower to `const std::string&`?

Comment: string_view is bad and will cause more problems than it solves. see: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/Gj5gt5E-po8%5B1-25%5D

Comment: @DrewDormann unordered containers don't support transparent comparators

Comment: @skeller: The issue discussed there is on the ease of conversion between the two. That has nothing to do with this.

Comment: `string_view` can be used to represent substrings efficiently (since it only maintains an offset and doesn't store any characters on its own). The benefit will depend on your particular workload.

Comment: @skeller Returning any view from a function is problematic no matter which one you use.

Comment: @skeller the discussion you link is about a flaw in the design. Claiming that views introduce more problems than they solve is a crude exaggeration imho

Comment: yes, i think i exaggerated the design flaw of string_view a bit, but be aware of its implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly propagate your needs and expectations up your API chain. Your lower-level code *needs* a `std::string`; it cannot work with anything else. So that need ought to be propagated up through code that interacts with it, and that with others.

You use `string_view` when the eventual consumer of that string can work with `string_view` or its pointer+size components (or the consumer intends to copy the string regardless). If it can't work with `string_view`, then you can't use it.

Comment: The problem is that the lower level code / API isn't just anything, it's the STL itself. So it seems rather absurd that we can't use one feature of the C++ standard with another.

Comment: @jeanluc: "The STL itself" didn't decide to use a map of `std::string`; that's your choice.